# msi installation error code 1603 in windows server 2003 R2

Tags: windows, windows-installer, windows-server-2003

Cannot install any .msi file in my system. It shows error code 1603 and exits the installation. My machine is running windows server 2003 R2 Standard Edition SP2.

Windows Installer is running, IIS is running. Below mentioned frameworks are installed in my machine.....

```
.NET Framework 1.1 Service Pack 1   ver: 1.1.4322
.NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2   ver: 2.2.30729
.NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 2   ver: 3.2.30729
.NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1   ver: 3.5.30729.01
.NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile   ver: 4.0.30319
.NET Framework 4.0 Full Package   ver: 4.0.30319
```

I have Admin privilege, Hard disk space is ok, I also tried to install in different folder other than C drive, System user is having Full Control Permission. I have tried most of the solutions available online, but can not solve the issue. Please help me. Here is event viewer log -

```
The description for Event ID ( 10011 ) in Source ( MsiInstaller ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: Product: Quick Heal AntiVirus -- Key not valid for use in specified state.
, (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), , .
```

MSI log -

```
Key not valid for use in specified state.

Property(S): UpgradeCode = {some code}
Property(S): TARGETDIR = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\
Property(S): SourceDir = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\QH0779.ins\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\
Property(S): ProductName = Quick Heal AntiVirus
Property(S): ProductCode = {some code}
Property(S): ProductVersion = 15.00
Property(S): Manufacturer = Quick Heal
Property(S): ARPCONTACT = Quick Heal Technologies Pvt. Ltd.
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = NEWERPRODUCTFOUND
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): VersionNT = 502
Property(S): VSDNETURLMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?
Property(S): VSDIISMSG = This setup requires Internet Information Server 4.0 or higher and Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000 or higher.  This setup cannot be installed on Windows 95, Windows 98, or Windows Me.  Please install Internet Information Server and run this setup again.
Property(S): VSDUIANDADVERTISED = This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic.
Property(S): VSDNETMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.
Property(S): VSDINVALIDURLMSG = The specified path '[2]' is unavailable. The Internet Information Server might not be running or the path exists and is redirected to another machine. Please check the status of this virtual directory in the Internet Services Manager.
Property(S): VSDVERSIONMSG = Unable to install because a newer version of this product is already installed.
Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDialog
Property(S): SFF_UpFldrBtn = UpFldrBtn
Property(S): SFF_NewFldrBtn = NewFldrBtn
Property(S): AdminMaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(S): MaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(S): DefaultUIFont = VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400
Property(S): FolderForm_AllUsers = ALL
Property(S): FolderForm_AllUsersVisible = 1
Property(S): AdminWelcomeForm_NextArgs = AdminFolderForm
Property(S): AdminFolderForm_PrevArgs = AdminWelcomeForm
Property(S): AdminFolderForm_NextArgs = AdminConfirmInstallForm
Property(S): AdminConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = AdminFolderForm
Property(S): WelcomeForm_NextArgs = FolderForm
Property(S): FolderForm_PrevArgs = WelcomeForm
Property(S): FolderForm_NextArgs = ConfirmInstallForm
Property(S): ConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = FolderForm
Property(S): ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS = 1
Property(S): {3B1F17A7-B130-42E0-B8C8-641064533B80} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\AMTEMP\
Property(S): {8C9AEBA0-1BCA-4E72-A32D-08E4300A0BB7} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\CONFIG\
Property(S): {DAB2A4E4-5D41-4F21-90AC-5EDE0D07E081} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\DOWNLOAD\
Property(S): {4E23FB71-EA43-4FFB-931F-DFB0138B57CE} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\DOWNTEMP\
Property(S): {2AF8F5FA-A766-44AA-B281-9DBFDB1EBCA7} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\EMGTEMP\
Property(S): {3F8EEA60-FAAF-4924-ADFD-7D2DC827A8F0} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\GPRODAT\
Property(S): {67A604B7-0D4D-49EB-A9C9-6E8860842BB4} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\LOGS\
Property(S): {A1E93433-F189-4CE6-A7D5-F87347FBC0B5} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\Quarantine\
Property(S): {F1107DCC-28A9-4FB8-B29F-7CC666501CA8} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\REPORT\
Property(S): {52613F6B-D75A-4EFD-9EBB-858B3E788C89} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\RMCLIMGS\
Property(S): {E223520E-5D8C-4B0E-846E-4FC2DAF412D1} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\RMDDB\
Property(S): {1BFE4BC9-8601-4940-9C08-C27AA568D032} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\RSDB\
Property(S): {503B3928-91EA-497F-B05A-E91429C259FD} = C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal AntiVirus\TEMP\
Property(S): CopyType = 3
Property(S): {230D3D31-CC39-450C-A97A-2FE927041C05} = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Quick Heal AntiVirus\
Property(S): REINSTALLMODE = amus
Property(S): PackageCode = {some code}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): ADDLOCAL = DefaultFeature
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(S): MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI = 1
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 3180
Property(S): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): VersionMsi = 4.05
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 3790
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 2
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 3
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(S): System16Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\NetHood\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\PrintHood\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\My Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): Intel = 15
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 2046
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 2441
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = Administrator
Property(S): UserSID = some code
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = my-server-name
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 19
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 18:09:55
Property(S): Date = 9/4/2014
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.1
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 5.2.3790.3959
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = Cell
Property(S): COMPANYNAME = abc
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\WINDOWS\Installer\6954e7.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\QH0779.ins\inst.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): MsiUISourceResOnly = 1
Property(S): Preselected = 1
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = D:\
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\QH0779.ins\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {75DEED91-7B14-49DC-A5F3-B60E633AC4A5}
=== Logging stopped: 9/4/2014  18:09:55 ===
```

Comment: It isn't possible to answer why this MSI failed without a complete MSI log.  It's also outside of the scope to answer why all MSI's would fail to install on your machine as this forum is for developers not end users.

Comment: Dear Christopher,  Plz read d qstion again. I have given msi log. And how can you say that its out of scope. Do you think that there will be different solution if those msi were developed by me. Ok, Just think that I have build a msi without any fault and now my msi cant be installed and I got that error. So what will be your answer now. Please help.

Comment: Dear Manas, please pay attention to Chris' comment. That is NOT a full verbose MSI log. You should do the install with a msiexec command line that includes /l*vx <path to text log file>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for helping me. But, as I was looking for a quick solution so I perform a System Repair. And now .msi can be installed. So, my suggestion is just perform a System Repair if you are getting error 1603. It worked in my case.

Comment: Did you try to reboot before running system restore? It might have been one of the recent windows hotfixes updating msiexec.exe or one of its components. 1603 errors can as a general rule **not** be solved automatically by a system restore.

Comment: For people who find this and want to make a full log file, please read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23945198/129130

Comment: Also check this article, KB2918614 Alters Windows Installer Behavior: http://windowsitpro.com/security/bug-or-feature-kb2918614-alters-windows-installer-behavior

Comment: I dint perform System Restore, I did System Repair using Installation CD